# Is there a standard convention for naming z-index layers?

Tags: html, sass

I want to create some sass variables to represent different z-index values, and would like to use a pre-existing naming convention if one exists. I'm looking for something like how Swing defines `root`, `layered`, `content`, and `glass` panes, or a pointer to some theory that I can use as a naming basis.

Comment: If you mean "default z-index" then there is no default z-indexes. Every element lays on each others, by order of appearance =)

Comment: I don't mean default z-index of elements in the DOM, but rather am curious about existing conventions, like if there are grid systems or naming conventions for how to stack items in the z-axis. Just using a number for the z-index is very flexible, but how often do you use more than, say, 12 different z indexes in a site?

Comment: then it's as I said: by appearance. Every next element has higher z-index, but that's not real z-index

Comment: z-index is all relative to how many elements are on the page. You could always set some predefined ranges for yourself: -1, 3000-5999, 6000-9999, etc and then name them accordingly.

* CSS positioning also has an effect on visual layering in HTML.

Answer (score 9):

After thinking about this a bit at work, here's what we came up with (wrapped in a Sass map):

```
$z-index: (
  'satellite'           :       5000,
  'skyscraper'          :       1000,
  'tower-block'         :       500,
  'house'               :       200,
  'bungalow-chimney'    :       110,
  'bungalow'            :       100,
  'shed'                :       50,
  'postbox'             :       10,
  'curb'                :       1,
  'pavement'            :       0,
  'pothole'             :      -10,
  'ditch'               :      -20,
  'sewer'               :      -100,
  'mine'                :      -300,
  'seabed'              :      -1000
);
```

Which is then referenced like so:

```
.foo {
  z-index: map-get($z-index, 'pothole');
}
```

Answer (score 6):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_of_the_Earth ?

Exosphere
Thermosphere
Mesosphere
Stratosphere
Troposphere
Crust
UpperMantle
Mantle
OuterCore
InnerCore

geeky enough for you?

Comment: I love it! I started thinking along this route, but I can't remember the layers of the atmosphere off the top of my head :/

Comment: google pretty much IS the top of my head :D

Answer (score 0):

We need to maintain the stacking order of the project covers, filter bar, location search modal, custom drop-down above the modal, and website navigation, in that order, from bottom to top. We can set up a Sass list, like so:

```
$elements: project-covers, sorting-bar, modals, navigation;
```

This list represents the order in which we want our elements to appear, from lowest to highest, with each index, or position, in the array representing the z-index of that element. We can use the Sass index function to assign a z-index value to each element.
For example:

```
.project-cover {
   z-index: index($elements, project-covers);
}
```

This would print out:

```
.project-cover {
   z-index: 1;
}
```

This is because project-cover is the first element in the list, at index 1, and the lowest element in our z-index stacking order. Let’s write the Sass for the rest of the items in our list:

```
.sorting-bar {
   z-index: index($elements, sorting-bar);
}
.modal {
   z-index: index($elements, modals);
}
.navigation {
   z-index: index($elements, navigation);
}
```

Now, our compiled CSS would look like this:

```
.project-cover {
   z-index: 1;
}
.sorting-bar {
   z-index: 2;
}
.modal {
   z-index: 3;
}
.navigation {
   z-index: 4;
}
```

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking for at all.

Comment: This is a novel approach to defining a z-index stacking order without hardcoding any integers. I like it!

Comment: Yes, that's right, I may not have understood your question, sorry, did not want to ask, but help, hug.